# Why does the U.S.S. Vengeance have an open saucer section?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

The U.S.S. Vengeance has an open saucer section with some structure protruding into the open space--which I think is the bridge. Here's a pic:

[image: U.S.S. Vengeance Open Saucer]

So what is it used for? I thought the purpose might have been to prevent fewer hits. Maybe enemy fire would pass through the opening? But there's no way Star Trek weapons are that inaccurate.

Comment: Because it looks more eeeeevil.

Comment: @Valorum Sure...like the D'deridex class Romulan Warbirds. A viable point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have any canonical answer, but we have semi-canonical reasons for other design aspects of Federation ships, such as placement and pairing of nacelles, that are mostly related to the shape and generation of warp fields. That would suggest that the gap in the saucer is related to design complications of a major ship system like the warp drive, shields, weapons, or sensors, and may be related to whatever experimental technologies were put into it by Khan.